# How do i transfer my Xbox one profile to a USB?

Tags: xbox-one

All of the YouTube answers are for Xbox 360 to move your 360 profile to your Xbox One, but I want to know how to move my Xbox One profile onto a random USB. Is it possible?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  I believe your profile is synced with the cloud, so you can just sign in on another Xbox One and should be good to go.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Br00TCn.gif

Answer (score 2):

Much like the comments have stated, there is 0 reason to save your profile to a USB,also as far as I am aware, there isn't even a way to do so.

If you want to move your account to a different system (maybe you bought a One-S) or play on a friend's console, all you need to do is login, then all of your info will simply automagically sync up. When your done at the friends house, you can lock up the account, delete it until next time, or just leave it as is depending on how much you trust them... Your home Xbox will resync everything you did on the other console once you login again.

Comment: 0 reason? If I remember correctly the very reason it existed, ever, was for people without internet connectivity. That is actually the reason why the feature existed on Xbox in the first place. You can't download anything from the cloud if you can't connect to it. I didn't even have to try very hard for that one reason and I'm sure there are more...

Answer (score 0):

The only way you could copy the profile is if you access the hard drive of the xbox offline through a computer or pc. Xbox One has removed that feature a long time ago because people could copy profiles to another Xbox and remove the passcode using hyperscript software.